# Angular UI bootstrap tooptip is not auto positioning

Tags: html, css, angular

I am using angular bootstrap for tooltip popover content. I am facing alignment issue.

By default I set the position as "right". So it is fine. But When I click on the last content, that time I am facing problem. It is not fully visbile for my case. It is hiding half.

Please look at this example,

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/MMNsno2FTjoBi4W4A3Nf?p=preview)

Not only the very last content, If I have more contents in the same row, scroll will come that time the element which one will reach the last to the screen width, that time also popover is hiding.

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('PopoverDemoCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.dynamicPopover = {
    content: 'Hello, World!',
    templateUrl: 'myPopoverTemplate.html',
    title: 'Title'
  };

  $scope.placement = {
    options: [
      'top',
      'top-left',
      'top-right',
      'bottom',
      'bottom-left',
      'bottom-right',
      'left',
      'left-top',
      'left-bottom',
      'right',
      'right-top',
      'right-bottom'
    ],
    selected: 'top'
  };

  $scope.htmlPopover = $sce.trustAsHtml('<b style="color: red">I can</b> have <div class="label label-success">HTML</div> content');
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
  <script src="example.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-controller="PopoverDemoCtrl">

    <h4>Triggers</h4>
    <p>
      <button uib-popover="I appeared on mouse enter!" popover-trigger="'mouseenter'" popover-placement="right" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Mouseenter</button>
      <button uib-popover="I appeared on mouse enter!" popover-trigger="'mouseenter'" popover-placement="right" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Mouseenter</button>
      <button uib-popover="I appeared on mouse enter!" popover-trigger="'mouseenter'" popover-placement="right" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Mouseenter</button>
      <button uib-popover="I appeared on mouse enter!" popover-trigger="'mouseenter'" popover-placement="right" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Mouseenter</button>
      <button uib-popover="I appeared on mouse enter!" popover-trigger="'mouseenter'" popover-placement="right left" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Mouseenter</button>
      <button uib-popover="I appeared on mouse enter!" popover-trigger="'mouseenter'" popover-placement="right" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Mouseenter</button>
      <button uib-popover="I appeared on mouse enter!" popover-trigger="'mouseenter'" popover-placement="left right" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Mouseenter</button>
      <button uib-popover="I appeared on mouse enter!" popover-trigger="'mouseenter'" popover-placement="right" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Mouseenter</button>
    </p>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: change last placement to bottom

Comment: last placement is not a content. Its div's width.  Multiple contents are there means scroll will come. That time how can I test?

Comment: you can use :last-child